# Is this workaround for Stripe integration correct

Tags: android, gradle, stripe-payments

I tried adding this dependency in gradle : 'com.stripe:stripe-android:17.1.1'
But this gave me this error :
[image: android studio logcat]

So I changed my gradle dependency to
`{implementation('com.stripe:stripe-android:17.1.1') { exclude group: "org.bouncycastle" }}`
Now I'm able to build the project successfully . Is this workaround correct or will there be any issues in future when I use stripe SDK functions .

Comment: You can't just exclude it no — that dependency is needed because it provides some cryptographic functions needed for 3D Secure. I'd probably start with https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/3333 and https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/3173 and try to fix the actual duplicate class error itself !